# Parsing XML attrib with Python, ' and " character spliting

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with the NVD XML and attempting to parse and split the XML to eventually enter into a DB. The issue I'm running into is the parsed XML attrib is either with " or ' around the values. I'm not able to split the strings of these. I've included the code and the entry that it currently fails on. The expected output is

```
product,america's_first_federal_credit_union,america's_first_fcu_mobile_banking
```

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import time
from subprocess import call
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import re

range_from = 2017
range_to = 2017

def process_entry(entry):
    cve = entry.attrib.get("name")
    print cve
    cpes = get_cpes_affected(entry)


def get_cpes_affected(entry):
    child = []
    for e in entry.iter():
        if "}prod" in e.tag:
            print e.attrib
            print unichr(34)
            if unichr(34) in e.attrib:
                print "hey yo"
                child.append("product," + str(e.attrib).split('"')[1] + "," + str(e.attrib).split('"')[3])
            else:
                child.append("product," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3] + "," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[7])
            #print e.tag, e.attrib
        if "'prev'" in e.attrib:
            child.append("version," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[7] + "," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3])
        if "}vers" in e.tag and "'prev'" not in e.attrib:
            child.append("version," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3] + ",")
            #print e.tag, e.attrib
    for derp in child:
        print derp

for i in range(range_from, range_to+1):
    os.system("wget -O tmp.zip https://nvd.nist.gov/download/nvdcve-%i.xml.zip" % i)
    os.system("unzip -o tmp.zip")
    e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('nvdcve-%i.xml' % i).getroot()

    for entry in e:
        process_entry(entry)
```

Example of an XML entry that is being parsed

```
    <entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2017-5916" seq="2017-5916" published="2017-05-05" modified="2017-05-16" severity="Medium" CVSS_version="2.0" CVSS_score="4.3" CVSS_base_score="4.3" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9" CVSS_exploit_subscore="8.6" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)">
<desc>
  <descript source="cve">The America's First Federal Credit Union (FCU) Mobile Banking app 3.1.0 for iOS does not verify X.509 certificates from SSL servers, which allows man-in-the-middle attackers to spoof servers and obtain sensitive information via a crafted certificate.</descript>
</desc>
<loss_types>
  <conf/>
</loss_types>
<range>
  <network/>
</range>
<refs>
  <ref source="MISC" url="https://medium.com/@chronic_9612/follow-up-76-popular-apps-confirmed-vulnerable-to-silent-interception-of-tls-protected-data-64185035029f" adv="1">https://medium.com/@chronic_9612/follow-up-76-popular-apps-confirmed-vulnerable-to-silent-interception-of-tls-protected-data-64185035029f</ref>
</refs>
<vuln_soft>
  <prod name="america's_first_fcu_mobile_banking" vendor="america's_first_federal_credit_union">
    <vers num="3.1.0" prev="1" edition=":~~~iphone_os~~"/>
  </prod>
</vuln_soft>
```

Entry it fails on

```
{'vendor': "america's_first_federal_credit_union", 'name': "america's_first_fcu_mobile_banking"}
```

And just to include an example of a string it's able to split without issue

```
{'vendor': 'emirates_nbd_bank_p.j.s.c', 'name': 'emirates_nbd_ksa'}
```

Sorry forgot to include the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prev-version-load.py", line 49, in <module>
    process_entry(entry)
  File "prev-version-load.py", line 18, in process_entry
    cpes = get_cpes_affected(entry)
  File "prev-version-load.py", line 33, in get_cpes_affected
    child.append("product," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3] + "," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[7])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: And the error you're getting is...?

Comment: Are you using lxml?

Comment: And what is the output you're trying to get? `str`ing a `dict` and then trying to parse it is almost certainly not what you want to be doing...

Comment: @JonClements added full code and xml, the expected output is this

product,emirates_nbd_bank_p.j.s.c,emirates_nbd

Comment: @Adthrawn what's the expected output for your example `entry` ?

Comment: @JonClements I added that to the top of the post

Comment: @Adthrawn I don't see any of that in your posted XML... can you either provide the output for the example you've provided or provide the XML for the expected output...

Comment: @JonClements added the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with parsing xml, but with how you format the output.

Unlike in shell scripting, where most things are just string and you can just do string fiddling to get the output you want, python is an object-oriented languages, objects in Python has types. In particular `e.attrib` is a dictionary type and you can't do string operations on a dictionary.

I'd suggest using ElementTree's `findall()` method instead of doing what I think you were trying to do. For example, I *think* this is what you are really trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

range_from = 2017
range_to = 2017

def process_entry(entry):
    cve = entry.attrib.get("name")
    print cve
    cpes = get_cpes_affected(entry)


def get_cpes_affected(entry):
    prods = entry.findall('nvd:vuln_soft/nvd:prod', namespaces=namespaces)
    for prod in prods:
        print prod.attrib
        print '"'
    for prod in prods:
        print "product,{},{}".format(prod.attrib['vendor'], prod.attrib['name'])
        for vers in prod.findall('nvd:vers', namespaces=namespaces):
            if vers.get('edition'):
                print "version,{},".format(vers.attrib['edition'])
            elif vers.get('prev') == '1':
                print "version,{},".format(vers.attrib['prev'])
            else:
                print "version,{},".format(vers.attrib['num'])


namespaces = {'nvd': 'http://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/cve/1.2'}
# OPTIONAL: registering namespace is useful for outputting XML with ET.tostring()/ET.dump()
#for prefix, ns in namespaces.items():
#    ET.register_namespace(prefix, ns)

for i in range(range_from, range_to+1):
    e = ET.parse('nvdcve-%i.xml' % i).getroot()

    for entry in e:
        process_entry(entry)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying and failing to do initially and then fell back on the weird not quite working hack I'm at now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing...

```
if "}prod" in e.tag:
    print unichr(34)
    if unichr(34) in e.attrib:
        print "hey yo"
        child.append("product," + str(e.attrib).split('"')[1] + "," + str(e.attrib).split('"')[3])
    else:
        child.append("product," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3] + "," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[7])
    #print e.tag, e.attrib
if "'prev'" in e.attrib:
    child.append("version," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[7] + "," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3])
if "}vers" in e.tag and "'prev'" not in e.attrib:
    child.append("version," + str(e.attrib).split("'")[3] + ",")
```

With...

```
reg=r"\"|'(?=[^\"]*')|'(?=\W*\")"
if "prod" in e.tag:
  #print(re.split(reg,str(e.attrib)))
  child.append("product," + re.split(reg,str(e.attrib))[3] + "," + re.split(reg,str(e.attrib))[7])
    #print e.tag, e.attrib
if "prev" in e.attrib:
    child.append("version," + re.split(reg,str(e.attrib))[7] + "," + re.split(reg,str(e.attrib))[3])
if "vers" in e.tag and "prev" not in e.attrib:
    child.append("version," + re.split(reg,str(e.attrib))[3] + ",")
```

Let me know if this works, I will explain.

---

**UPDATE**

Even better solution is below:-

```
    if "prod" in e.tag:
        #print(e.attrib)
        child.append("product," + e.attrib['name'] + "," + e.attrib['vendor'])
    if "prev" in e.attrib:
        child.append("version," + e.attrib['prev'] + "," + e.attrib['num'])
    if "vers" in e.tag and "prev" not in e.attrib:
        child.append("version," + e.attrib['num'] + ",")
```

A working example with your given xml is [here](https://repl.it/MKGx/0) for all three cases yours, my original solution and updated solution.

Comment: Ah, the second solution is much better than the hodgepodge I was trying. I had tried to use XPATH to pull the fields without doing the ifs but I was failing that.

Comment: @Adthrawn: the stdlib's xml.etree does not support xpath. If you want to use xpath, you should use [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml)'s [etree](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).